# Is it correct to use LocalDateTime to save the time for a web application that only supports one time zone? (Java, Springboot, Postgresql)

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate, date

My web application should handle only one time zone. It is specified in many sources to keep the date always in UTC. But in my case, following the KISS rule, is reasonable to use LocalDateTime in entities and totally ignore the timezone. What do you think?

Comment: instead of ignoring timezone, set the one time zone that you are currently supporting

Comment: maybe using `Instant`?

Comment: "Where possible, applications should use LocalDate, LocalTime and LocalDateTime to better model the domain. For example, a birthday should be stored in a code LocalDate. Bear in mind that any use of a time-zone, such as 'Europe/Paris', adds considerable complexity to a calculation. Many applications can be written only using LocalDate, LocalTime and Instant, with the time-zone added at the user interface (UI) layer. " - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html